# wrong final block length in AESCrypt

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, encryption, aescryptoserviceprovider

Am using AESCrypt for encrypt and Decrypt the Email address stored in the db.
Encryption is working. But during Decryption  wrong final block length error was occur.

Error

```
OpenSSL::Cipher::CipherError in DashboardUsersController#index
```

In User model:

```
after_validation(on: :create) do
    self.email= AESCrypt.encrypt(email, "password")
end
```

In UsersController:

```
   if @users != nil then
      @users.each do |usr|
        usrEmail = usr.email
       usr.email = AESCrypt.decrypt(usrEmail, "password")
      end
    end
```

In user_view.html.rb

```
<th>Email id</th>
<td><%= user.email %></td>
```

Comment: You are calling `after_validation` twice

Comment: sorry. I give after_validation once but it shows the wrong final block length error.@Stefan